# np++ replace block with regex

Tags: regex

I have a text like this:

```
faretel.lhk@gmail.com:hanow728064
2015-12-23 07.52.11.jpg                                     2138KB                     23/12/2015 00:52:11
variable text kjdfjksdf
2015-12-24 13.59.43.jpg                                     2609KB                     24/12/2015 06:59:43
2016-05-04 13.16.55.jpg                                     2309KB                     04/05/2016 07:16:55
variable text kjdfjksdf
2016-12-09 12.32.38.jpg                                     1407KB                     09/12/2016 05:32:38
2016-12-09 12.46.24.jpg                                     1024KB                     09/12/2016 05:46:24
2016-12-09 12.48.04.jpg                                     1119KB                     09/12/2016 05:48:04
2016-12-09 18.19.28.jpg                                     1427KB                     09/12/2016 11:19:28

============================================
stuytu652nd@yahoo.com:ortyrgell966
2016-12-09 14.02.43.jpg                                     1051KB                     09/12/2016 07:02:43
2016-12-09 14.05.34.jpg                                     1083KB                     09/12/2016 07:05:34
2016-12-09 16.38.44.jpg                                     2709KB                     09/12/2016 09:38:44
2016-12-09 16.41.59.jpg                                     1677KB                     09/12/2016 09:41:59
variable text 9df454645
2016-12-09 16.43.47.jpg                                     1424KB                     09/12/2016 09:43:47
2016-12-09 16.57.30.jpg                                     2988KB                     09/12/2016 09:57:30                                          371KB

============================================
```

I use regex: `(?-s).*\R\K(?s:.+?)(?=^.+@|\z)`  to select the range of lines until the next email, but if click on replace (empty) I can't delete this selection. **How to delete my selection?**

I need regex which selects the range of lines between the two emails (with Find) and then with Replace (empty) delete them.

Comment: Have you tried using "replace all", if it is applicable to your problem.

Comment: Which version of notepad++ are you using? It works for me with v7.7.1

Answer (score 1):

Seems as the "replace" functionality has some problems with `\K`

I did some slight modification to the regex:

```
(?-s)(.*\R)(?s:.+?)(?=^.+@|\z)
```

And replace with

```
\1
```

So basically match as before, but instead of ignoring the email (first capturing group), match everything and replace by the previously captured email.